# Renaming a column entry, when it is the maximum value by group, gives inconsistent results

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, max

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- structure(list(State_Ab = c("VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", 
"VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", 
"VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", 
"VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", 
"VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA"), year = c(1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2017, 2017, 2017, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007
), County = c("Bedford", "Fairfax", "Bedford", "Fairfax", "Bedford", 
"Fairfax", "Bedford", "Fairfax", "Bedford", "Bedford", "Fairfax", 
"Fairfax", "Bedford", "Bedford", "Fairfax", "Fairfax", "Bedford", 
"Bedford", "Fairfax", "Fairfax", "Bedford", "Bedford", "Fairfax", 
"Fairfax", "Bedford", "Fairfax", "Fairfax", "Bedford", "Bedford", 
"Fairfax", "Fairfax", "Bedford", "Fairfax", "Fairfax", "Fairfax", 
"Fairfax", "Bedford", "Bedford", "Bedford", "Fairfax", "Bedford", 
"Fairfax", "Bedford", "Fairfax", "Bedford", "Fairfax"), Type = c("B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Population = c(15528, 297214, 
2053, 7505, 8963, 199282, 829, 4299, 20040, 2018, 9095, 392987, 
26930, 2319, 10225, 448078, 24499, 1935, 8048, 340397, 24012, 
1926, 7112, 303379, 41681, 479086, 9552, 31404, 2542, 10546, 
461379, 42525, 551183, 12028, 303203, 7600, 2160, 17988, 25284, 
410475, 2379, 9462, 25122, 342998, 1940, 8096)), row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Some of these values are for Bedford City, some for Bedford County. Based on the information I have, the min value should be Bedford City, the max value Bedford County. I thought I would do the following, but it fails somehow.
I would like to do the following, based on [Ronak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338125/renaming-a-column-entry-when-it-is-the-maximum-value-by-group) :

```
DT[County=="Bedford" & order(Population), County := c("Bedford County", "Bedford City"), .(State_Ab, year, County, Type)]
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, County == "Bedford" & order(Population), `:=`(County,  : 
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 4 in column 'County'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

The output then becomes:

```
   State_Ab year         County Type Population
 1:       VA 2017        Bedford    B      41681
 2:       VA 2005        Bedford    A      31404
 3:       VA 2005        Bedford    A       2542
 4:       VA 2017        Bedford    A      42525
 5:       VA 1995        Bedford    C       2160
 6:       VA 1995        Bedford    C      17988
 7:       VA 2001        Bedford    C      25284
 8:       VA 2001        Bedford    C       2379
 9:       VA 2007        Bedford    C      25122
10:       VA 2007        Bedford    C       1940
11:       VA 1995   Bedford City    B       2053
12:       VA 1999   Bedford City    B        829
13:       VA 2001   Bedford City    B       2018
14:       VA 2005   Bedford City    B       2319
15:       VA 2007   Bedford City    B       1935
16:       VA 2011   Bedford City    B       1926
17:       VA 1995 Bedford County    B      15528
18:       VA 1999 Bedford County    B       8963
19:       VA 2001 Bedford County    B      20040
20:       VA 2005 Bedford County    B      26930
21:       VA 2007 Bedford County    B      24499
22:       VA 2011 Bedford County    B      24012
```

I do not really understand where this issue is coming from..

When try the other county in the data-set, I do:

```
DT[County=="Fairfax" & order(Population), County := c("Fairfax County", "Fairfax City"), .(State_Ab, year, County, Type)]
```

I get no error, but the output is wrong (Fairfax County is MUCH larger than Fairfax City, but it not always is in the data):

```
23:       VA 1995   Fairfax City    B       7505
24:       VA 1999   Fairfax City    B       4299
25:       VA 2001   Fairfax City    B     392987
26:       VA 2005   Fairfax City    B     448078
27:       VA 2007   Fairfax City    B     340397
28:       VA 2011   Fairfax City    B     303379
29:       VA 2017   Fairfax City    B       9552
30:       VA 2005   Fairfax City    A     461379
31:       VA 2017   Fairfax City    A      12028
32:       VA 1995   Fairfax City    C       7600
33:       VA 2001   Fairfax City    C       9462
34:       VA 2007   Fairfax City    C       8096
35:       VA 1995 Fairfax County    B     297214
36:       VA 1999 Fairfax County    B     199282
37:       VA 2001 Fairfax County    B       9095
38:       VA 2005 Fairfax County    B      10225
39:       VA 2007 Fairfax County    B       8048
40:       VA 2011 Fairfax County    B       7112
41:       VA 2017 Fairfax County    B     479086
42:       VA 2005 Fairfax County    A      10546
43:       VA 2017 Fairfax County    A     551183
44:       VA 1995 Fairfax County    C     303203
45:       VA 2001 Fairfax County    C     410475
46:       VA 2007 Fairfax County    C     342998
```

This is driving me absolutely nuts.. What is going on here?

Desired result:

```
23:       VA 1995   Fairfax City    B       7505
24:       VA 1999   Fairfax City    B       4299
25:       VA 2001   Fairfax County  B     392987
26:       VA 2005   Fairfax County  B     448078
27:       VA 2007   Fairfax County  B     340397
28:       VA 2011   Fairfax County  B     303379
29:       VA 2017   Fairfax City    B       9552
30:       VA 2005   Fairfax County  A     461379
31:       VA 2017   Fairfax City    A      12028
32:       VA 1995   Fairfax City    C       7600
33:       VA 2001   Fairfax City    C       9462
34:       VA 2007   Fairfax City    C       8096
35:       VA 1995 Fairfax County    B     297214
36:       VA 1999 Fairfax County    B     199282
37:       VA 2001 Fairfax City      B       9095
38:       VA 2005 Fairfax City      B      10225
39:       VA 2007 Fairfax City      B       8048
40:       VA 2011 Fairfax City      B       7112
41:       VA 2017 Fairfax County    B     479086
42:       VA 2005 Fairfax City      A      10546
43:       VA 2017 Fairfax County    A     551183
44:       VA 1995 Fairfax County    C     303203
45:       VA 2001 Fairfax County    C     410475
46:       VA 2007 Fairfax County    C     342998
```

Comment: What's your desired ouput? Can you add it in your question?

Comment: @PeaceWang added. The higher pop should be Fairfax County. Fairfax County is MUCH larger than Fairfax City, but it not always is in the output.

Comment: @Tom it maybe have been easier to understand your question with a smaller example.

Comment: @Suren, I understand. But I ended up here in the first place because I over-simplified the problem. I wanted to make sure I did not make the same mistake again. I do not think it could have been much simpler either..

Comment: Try to examine to what your first argument evaluates to. Logical vector and integer vector combined with & looks very suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using an function to order County and Population, and then change the County accordingly.

I noticed that `VA 2017 Bedford    A` has only one entry for that year.

```
fn2 <- function(County, Population) {

 if (length(County) == 1) {
    return(list(County, Population))
 }  else {
    list(County = paste(County, c("City", "County")), 
        Population = sort(Population))
 }
}

DT[County == "Bedford", c("County", "Population") := fn2(County, Population), 
            .(State_Ab, year, Type)]
```

> ```
> part of DT
>     State_Ab year         County Type Population
>  1:       VA 1995   Bedford City    B       2053
>  2:       VA 1995        Fairfax    B     297214
>  3:       VA 1995 Bedford County    B      15528
>  4:       VA 1995        Fairfax    B       7505
>  5:       VA 1999   Bedford City    B        829
>  6:       VA 1999        Fairfax    B     199282
>  7:       VA 1999 Bedford County    B       8963
>  8:       VA 1999        Fairfax    B       4299
>  9:       VA 2001   Bedford City    B       2018
> 10:       VA 2001 Bedford County    B      20040
> 11:       VA 2001        Fairfax    B       9095
> 12:       VA 2001        Fairfax    B     392987
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to account for `Type` as well? I tried `DT[County=="Bedford", c("County", "Population") := fn(County, Population), 
            .(State_Ab, year, Type)] `, but then I still get the same error..

Comment: In this example it does not matter, but for my actual data, I need to able to account for it.

Comment: I just looked at the lines of your output, but the issue seems to persist.

Comment: Why did you try `County=="Bedford"`? Do you only want to change for Bedford?

Comment: I changed my answer to include Type. I do no get an error.

Comment: The actual data has hundreds of counties, only some of them have the issue that the city and county is named the same. For those I need to figure out which is which, for the other I just leave them

Comment: I am going out of my mind. I just will not work on my actual data. It keeps saying: `Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 7 of size 1 in column 'County'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.`

Comment: I just noticed that there is only one entry for `VA 2017 Bedford    A` but I was expecting two... I didn't expect this. I was expecting two number of each of the combination. I edited the answer this should fix for this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me mad. I should probably mentioned that the data was not that clean (I am using your solution as part of the cleaning process). It works now, the only thing it skips are the `2017` years, because it has no comparison there I guess. I will have to think of something for that. In any case, I am really really grateful, thank you so much.

Comment: It is **not skipping**. I just left the single entries as they are. You may change the first past of the if statement if you want to add "city' or "county" to the County.